# How to access networking singleton object in separate thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, networking

My singleton networking object:

```
public class Communication implements Runnable{

    private static Communication mInstance = null;

    private BufferedOutputStream socketOutput = null;
    private PrintWriter printOut = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private Scanner reader = null;          

   public static Communication getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new Communication();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }  

    public void login()
    {  //login functionality
         }
    public void run()
    {
        //connect to server using loopback address
        try{
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.3", 4242);

            //set inputs and out puts
            socketOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            printOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            reader = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch( UnknownHostException uhe){
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch( IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity where I want this object to be instantiated

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(Communication.getInstance()).start();  
  }
}
```

That part works fine. I instantiate communication object in a new thread and connection is established. Now that I want to access that object from another activity, unless I do getInstance() in a new thread again I get NetworkOnMainThread exception.

1. Does it mean every time I want to use my networking object I have to start a new thread ?
2. If (1) is yes:
   How can I access return value of Communication.getInstance().login() from main thread and put it inside view object ?

Comment: Your singleton is set up just fine.  Having a thread shouldn't matter.  Maybe you could be a little more clear on exactly what you're trying to do and what's having trouble?

Comment: When I put networking code inside the singleton object I have an NetworkingOnMainThread exception. So I believe I need to create that object in separate thread. How do I do that ? Once it's done, will I be able to access that object from main thread ?

Comment: You don't need to create the object on another thread.  You have to do the networking calls on another thread.  The object can be created on any thread, so long as the networking calls aren't in the constructor.  As for accessing an object for multiple threads-  its legal, but you need to be careful of race conditions, especially when editing variables on one or both threads.  But a full discussion of all those pitfalls takes books, not comments.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I guess I wasn't clear. Could you take  a look at the rephrased question ?